# How to make block draggable within a certain block only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a small problem. I pasted my code [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJyvVE).

My problem is this: I want to make my `window` `div` (`<div id="window"> Drag me </div>`) draggable only within `warp` div.

HTML code:

```
<div id="warp">
    <div id="window">
        Drag me
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #e67e22;
}

#window {
    width: 150px;
    height: 200px;
    //background-color: #1abc9c;
    border: 2px solid #16a085;
    padding: 20px;
}

#warp {
    margin: 10px;
    width: 700px;
    height: 600px;
    border: 2px solid #e74c3c;
}
```

JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#window").draggable();
});
```

I mean when I drag it with mouse then it shouldn't go out of `warp` div.

Comment: Are you trying to prevent it from being dragged outside of the warp div or allow it to be dragged outside of the warp div?

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
$( "#window" ).draggable({
      containment: 'parent'
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#window").draggable ({
    containment : "#warp"
  });
```